# Performance Testing with Cypress Lighthouse - Against a website that starts from a Third-Party Auth Login Page

Tags: automation, cypress, amazon-cognito, performance-testing, lighthouse

I tried to look into this guide: https://github.com/mfrachet/cypress-audit/issues/65 (and many similar ones on the internet) but still cannot resolve my issue.

Basically, I am writing performance test cases in Cypress for my website.
It launches from a third-party Amazon Cognito sign-in page.
So when I go to my website, at first it will redirect me to the Cognito sign-in page, and then after signing in, I will be redirected back to the home page of my website.
What I want to test is the performance metrics of different actions performed on my website. But no matter what, I have to go through the login process.

Here's the problem that I encounter:

- If the current browser hasn't yet previously signed in to my site, and so there's no cache (relating to this site) being stored in the browser, when I go to the site, the Cognito page will have a button allowing me to sign-in through my organization's SSO.
- But if the current browser already has been previously used to sign in to my site, and so there's cache storing the previous sign-in data, when I go to the site again, the Cognito page will look different. It will have a button allowing me to Continue to my site (ie. the button shows something like 'Continue with `<my organization>`'). After clicking on it, I need not to enter passwords from the SSO again, and I am directly signed in.
- I understand that lighthouse() command in cypress-audit first performs whatever actions I would like to test against, and then opens a new tab in order to estimate the performance metrics, and finally the new tab closes and resumes the Cypress test. So I encounter the "Continue button" mentioned above in this step, in the new tab (that lighthouse() tries to open).

---

So my question here is:

- On the new tab, my testing script could not proceed further, because there isn't any sign-in button appearing on the new tab opened by lighthouse(), but instead, there's a "Continue button".
- So the lighthouse() command got stuck there, causing the metrics measured to be 0. (Kinda frustrating because it obviously does not pass any threshold.)
- My workaround: manually click the "Continue button" whenever the test script encounters that page.
- Is there any way to have lighthouse() command automate this step?

Thanks. Feel free to comment.
PS Since my codes are private, I am unfortunately unable to share in the community, but feel free to arrange meetings with me to review and solve it together.
Look forward to any solutions in the community!